# Can we handle millions of requests using FastAPI?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, server-side-rendering, fastapi

We are building a platform using microservice-based architecture. We are expecting 500K users in the next two years so for that we are thinking to use below technology stack as below:

- Python - Fast API
- UI - React SSR (Server Side Rendering)

Here, we found during concurrency analysis that node is faster than Fast API.
We are confused that should we go with nodeJS or Fast API (asyncio). We have more expertise in python so more leaning towards it but we do not want to bias in the selection of technology which later on creates problems for us.

So we need guidance the shall we proceed with Python to handle millions of requests using - Fast API  or we should go with node?

Or If you think we can have a better technology option then above then we are open for suggestions.

Comment: Can we handle millions of requests using FastAPI? No.. In a perfect world the limit is 64k concurrent users, to handle 500k you would need to load balance it (8+ instances), then the speed of code execution is not much of a concern

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - Yes, we would have a load balancer for sure. The main concern is FastAPI which uses asyncio, so can we bat on it for a lot of concurrent users?